# Can not create webhook using woocommerce API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

First I create an API consumer key and secret with read_write permission. (Either manually from the UI or programmatically using the API)

Then, i use the `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` as query parameters to consume the API: create a webhook for example. So i did:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://wp.mee/wordpress496/wp-json/wc/v3/webhooks?consumer_key=ck_7cc776be8d22b6841b0d62a96a50e975e7523343&consumer_secret=cs_7b788da4bf6063f8dff4b0463c1e9693fdee7a5b' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"name":"ProWebSms","topic":"order.created","delivery_url":"https://dev.smshare.fr/api/v2/woo/webhooks/all/7235173095214b608914159bea2360eb"}'
```

I get the following message:

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Using the basic authentication mechanism fails also. I created a test.php just to be sure that the authorization header is not stripped out by the server and i can confirm that the header is there.

```
<?php var_dump(apache_request_headers()); ?>

//i can see:
'Authorization'
'Basic Y2tfN2NjNzc2YmU4ZDIyYjY4NDFiMGQ2MmE5NmE1MGU5NzVlNzUyMzM0Mzpjc183Yjc4OGRhNGJmNjA2M2Y4ZGZmNGIwNDYzYzFlOTY5M2ZkZWU3YTVi'
```

Tried on both:

- woocommerce version 3.3.5
- wordpress version: 4.9.6

And:

- woocommerce version 3.5.4
- wordpress version: 5.0.3

---

EDIT

I noticed that if I replace `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` by the admin user username/password (ex: admin:admin) the call succeeds.

The `wp_authenticate_username_password` is being called..

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. You must be using HTTPS.
This make testing in local environments hard.